# JSON - How to give onclick element in script?

Tags: javascript, json

How to give onclick function for id in JavaScript? eg: my onclick function is `oclick="function('#id')"` and I need action to be made in div. My each buttons contain their own `id`'s. But I couldnt figure out how to use this element to generate using JSON.

I prefer JavaScript rathar than jquery.

```
function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i;
    for(i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
        out += '<button onclick="function('#' + arr[i].ids + '')">' +
        arr[i].blaah + '</button><br>';
    }
    document.getElementById("id01").innerHTML = out;
}
```

Comment: `How to give onclick function for id in JavaScript of JSON?` I understand the words, and even parts of the sentence, but put them all together and it sounds like you're middle management trying to baffle the upper management with jargon that they wont understand but they'll think you know what you're talking about ... in other words ... what?!?

Comment: `If not possible with JavaScript then someone can help me out with jquery` - jquery **IS** javascript - therefore if it's not possible in javascript then it's not possible in jquery

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: use this

```
function yourfunction(elem){
//elem contains the button
//you could do:
elem.style.display="none";
}
```

In your html do:

```
<div onclick="yourfunction(this)">Button</div>
```

For shure this can be created dynamically.
If you want to keep your code, dont get confused with " and ' .
" ' " for example: the second " closes the first, even if theres an opened '. And you cannot name a function function. Thats an syntax error. Do this:

```
 "<button onclick=\'func('#elem')\' >test</button>";
```

Comment: but what if i need to call onclick function from a div? So, ID is must right?

Comment: So, what will I write instead? could you update the answer? That what im really looking for. Sorry, my mistake that i did not mention this in Question.

Comment: Im sorry, my bad explanation and english make a misunderstanding. I updated my question. I need action to be made in div with the click of button

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```js
var arr = ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"]

function onClick() {
    alert("you clicked button with id: " + this.id);
}

function createButtons(arr) {
    var out = document.getElementById("out");
    for (var i = 0, l = arr.length; i < l; i++) {
        var node = document.createElement("button");
        node.id = arr[i];
        node.innerHTML = "button " + arr[i];
        node.addEventListener("click", onClick, false);
        out.appendChild(node);
    }
}

createButtons(arr);
```

```html
<div id="out">
</div>
```